# I'm trying to /testfor a player on a block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a command block that when a player walks over a block, it will detect the player and activate another command block with a different command. I tried:

`/testfor @p {coordinates of the block}`

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#testfor) page from the Minecraft wiki, you also need to specify a radius within the block to check for the player.

> To count the number of players in survival mode within a 3-block radius of (0,64,0):
>
> `testfor @a[0,64,0,r=3,m=0]`

(The `r=` isn't strictly necessary, but it makes the command a little clearer.)

Comment: Just tested it, works on 1.8.1

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute if entity @a[x=0,y=64,z=0,distance=..3,gamemode=survival]`